# Adding Header Rows Using Tableone() and kable() in R

Tags: r, html-table, r-markdown

Suppose I have the following code for producing a baseline table:

```
library(tableone)

# Create a sample data frame
data <- data.frame(
  Group = rep(c("A", "B", "C"), each = 10),
  Age = c(25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 55, 60, 65, 70,
          22, 27, 33, 38, 42, 47, 52, 58, 63, 68,
          28, 31, 36, 41, 46, 51, 56, 61, 66, 71),
  Score = c(85, 78, 92, 63, 75, 88, 71, 79, 94, 82,
            90, 72, 84, 61, 77, 89, 68, 75, 91, 80,
            87, 79, 93, 66, 73, 86, 70, 76, 92, 81)
)

# Convert the data frame to a table using tableone
table1 <- CreateTableOne(
  vars = c("Age", "Score"),
  data = data,
  factorVars = c("Group")
)

# Print the table
print(table1)
```

First, I want to be able to put a heading over the variables (n, Age, Score) in the tableone that reads "Characteristics."

Second, I want to add an empty header row between the "Age" and "Score" rows called "Split."

Is there a way to do this directly using the CreateTableOne() function, or do I need to use kable() formatting in R markdown?